Using divergent sums to define other divergent sums
In this post, Annix describes an extension to the real numbers that includes a logarithm of 0, which could allow the definition of several divergent integrals and sums. However, this does not include all divergent sums. This made me think about the possibility of defining any divergent sum.
In order to start this process, let us create a divergent sum then convert its terms into a Taylor Series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha_k n^k$$
Since rising factorials can be denoted as polynomials, we can then use the Stirling Numbers ($s(n,k)$) to write:
$$n^{\bar{k}}=\sum_{p=0}^{k} s(k,p) n^p\rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha_k n^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k n^{\bar{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \sum_{p=0}^{k} s(k,p) n^p$$
Since this is a divergent sum, we should not be able to switch the sum operators, but let's ignore that rule:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k n^{\bar{k}} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta_k n^{\bar{k}}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{\bar{k}}$$
Based on an earlier equation, we can substitute $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{\bar{k}}$ with $\omega^k$ to find:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k n^{\bar{k}} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta_k n^{\bar{k}}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{\bar{k}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta_k \omega^k$$
Therefore, we can define any divergent sum as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha_k n^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta_k n^{\bar{k}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \beta_k \omega^k=\beta_1\omega+\beta_2\omega^2+\beta_3\omega^3+...$$
Once we find all of our $\beta_k$'s, we can define any divergent sum using this method.
I used Wolfram to find another representation of $\omega^k$ to be:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{\bar{k}}=\omega^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+k)!}{n!}=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(k+m+1)!}{k!(m+1)}$$
That being said, how do I find all of the $\beta_k$ from all of the $\alpha_k$?
Update
I found another solution to this divergent sum problem, $\sum_n a_n=a_0+a_1\omega$, where $\omega$ is a general infinity. While it does not take any later terms into account, I found that this approach does work for continued fractions. I will try to find another approach that involves all $a_n$.

Are you ultimately evaluating your $\omega_k$ via linear combinations of the riemann zeta function at negative arguments? Those sums are non-alternating polynomials so I don't see how else you plan to give them divergent assignments.

@SidharthGhoshal the bar on top of the k in $n^\bar{k}$ represents the rising factorial. While I would expect different "versions" of the zeta function at negative arguments to work, I do not believe you can use linear combinations... I could be wrong though.

The rising factorial $n^{\bar{k}}$ is a $k^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial in $n$ and therefore can be expanded is $a_0 n^k + a_1 n^{k-1} + ... a_k $ for suitable coefficients $a_i$. Therefore an infinite sum of the rising factorials is just a linear combination of $a_0 \zeta(-k) + a_1 \zeta(1-k) + ... $ when regularized by standard methods.

@SidharthGhoshal, thank you for the clarification! You learn something new every day!

This is a comment as I have yet to verify your Stirling number procedure but a closely related procedure involving the Riemann Zeta function does not sum the geometric series correctly.
We recall that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^n = \frac{1}{1-e}$$
Note that $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ and therefore:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n)^k}{k!} $$
Doing the "questionable rearrangement" we conjecture that:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  n^k $$
And therefore:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^n = 1 +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(-k)}{k!} $$
But this is wrong. We are off by a $-1$. The Euler Maclaurin formula correctly expresses:
$$ \frac{1}{1-e^x} = \mathbf{-\frac{1}{x}}  +1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(-k)}{k!}  $$
A moral of the story here is that these kind of re-arrangements often get you "symbolically close" to where you want to go but they aren't correct (of course your stirling number formulation might work I haven't shown it doesn't yet). More specifically the parts that you did re-arrange are often symbolically correct BUT there is extra stuff that you lose by naively re-arranging sums.
A better approach to understanding these things is instead to consider the function $\hat{f}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor } a_n$ and calculate the average value of the $O(1)$ terms of $\hat{f}(x)$. This post explores that and it works surprisingly well on everything from convergent sums, to the harmonic series to the geometric series and many things in between including the infamous $1+2+3... = -\frac{1}{12}$.
Unfortunately this too has limitations for example it fails to assign divergent continued fractions correctly so a more general technique needs to be invented to unify all these cases.

I did not consider those rearrangements to be troublesome, however, you may be right. I originally wanted to put divergent sums in terms of negative powers of zero, of which seems harder than I expected it to be. I do agree on the arrangement being "questionable" though! I will definitely check out the other post, thank you for bringing it to my attention!
